How to burn total issuance
I have a solo chain with a total issuance of 10 billion tokens. I need to reduce this number to 5 million. What is the best way to burn the excess tokens to set the total issuance to 5 million?

Use sudo like Shubham said. Or you can use governance to get the root origin.
And I think using burn is better than force_set_balance.
Also, you can write migration code by calling burn_from in the runtime.

You can set balance of a particular account using force_set_balance method of balances pallet. It sets a new free balance for a particular account you just need to pass the amount you want that account and it will be set. I am assuming you have your supply in some wallets and you need to burn the supply from them. To execute this function you must use sudo account.
